# Transaction atomic needed for bulk create?

Tags: python, django, database

I'm using the [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method from Django to create many entries at once.

To ensure that the changes are only committed if there is no exception I'm thinking about adding [`transaction.atomic()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) to the code blocks but I'm not sure if I need to add it.

From my understanding I only need to add it in **Scenario 2** because in this case I'm executing more than one query.

**Scenario 1**

Create 1.000 entries in one query

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
    Entry(headline='This is a test'),
    Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
    # ...
])
```

**Scenario 2**

Create 10.000 entries in in batches of 1.000

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
    Entry(headline='This is a test'),
    Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
    # ...
], batch_size=1_000)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you don't have to for either scenario. According to the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/models/query.py#L561), using transaction atomic would be redundant for `bulk_create` as that method already uses atomic transactions.

Comment: Yes ... "transactions are important in scenarios like this," and yes, "therefore, Django already does them for you."  (Transactions are needed more for "locking efficiency" than *per se* "rollbacks.")