# Is django's bulk_create atomic?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Will Django rolls back changes if there is any failure while batch creation of objects using `bulk_create()` in django? Or should I explicitly use `transaction.atomic()`?

I have Foreignkey references in my models which might not be present in database.

I'm using Django 1.11

Comment: This is not specified in the docs. so i think you have to put you own transaction atomic around it to have that kind of effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) produces single query if there is no batch_size set ( except for SQLite where batch is 999)

You should do transaction.atomic() block only if you set batch_size and you want all previous batches to be reverted

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the related question [Transaction atomic needed for bulk create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285826/transaction-atomic-needed-for-bulk-create) indicates that `bulk_create()` is atomic by default, therefore there is no need for `transaction.atomic()`.